# string base64_encode/decode fails?

Tags: php, base64

I have this script:

```
    function is_base64($s){
        // Check if there are valid base64 characters
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\r\n+]*={0,2}$/', $s)) return false;

        // Decode the string in strict mode and check the results
        $decoded = base64_decode($s, true);
        if(false === $decoded) return false;

        // Encode the string again
        if(base64_encode($decoded) != $s) return false;

        return true;
    }
```

called by `is_base64($input)`

where `$input` is two strings I try to test against the function.

This is reported ok  : `!!K0deord*test`

This is reported not ok : `Kilroy2P4All`

What could be the difference that makes it return false?

Comment: The regex is unnecessary when decoding using the `$strict` argument. Something like, `return !(base64_decode($s, true)===false);` should be enough.

Comment: True. See next answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decoding the value using the `$strict` argument, which means that the regular expression is not needed (the decoding will simply fail if there are invalid characters in the string).

Encoding the decoded string is also not needed. If the encoded string is successfully decoded then it is valid; encoding it again does not change the validity of anything.

Something like this should be sufficient to validate a base64-encoded string:

```
function is_base64($s) {
    return ! (base64_decode($s, true) === false);
}
```

It simply decodes the value and then returns whether or not it succeeded or failed.